# only one record displayed in my report

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I designed a report in SSRS, its not a tabular report, but a custom one. When I preview my report, why cant I navigate to next record? The query which is the data-set of this report has about 1000 records, but my report in Preview mode doesn't recognize that and just displays "1 or 1" in the top menu bar. How can I navigate to other records?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, It sounds like you have only designed one page, not a repeating data element. If you designed your page by dragging data fields onto the blank background, then the text boxes that you get will only show the first result from your data set.

You need to use an item that will repeat its contents for every data record: List, Table, or Matrix, all variants of a Tablix.

To build complex layouts that repeat for every record, you should either:

- Create a parent and subreport (which takes a parameter to filter the
  query to a single record.) Put the subreport into a list or table.
- Place a rectangle into a list or table, and build your report in that rectangle.

Either way, note that your textboxes are contained in the repeating item.

Comment: Did you mean putting controls in a rectangle instead of putting a rectangle in controls? If not, how would I put a rectangle in a table? Lets say I have a query whose output I need to display in a report(not in tabular format), how would I approach this? Should I follow the Create a report wizard and use my query then move the column header and placeholders created by wizard(from tablix) to the rectangle and then delete the tablix?